# Usar servidor propio con phonegap

Tags: javascript, phonegap

Buenas! Estoy intentando probar mi aplicacion en phonegap. Mi aplicacion consta de un directorio "Public" con el front-end, y una carpeta "Server" con el servidor. Si copio todo el contenido del directorio "Public" en el directorio www de un proyecto de phonegap puedo ver el contenido en el movil pero sin poder acceder a mi propio servidor ni mi base de datos.

Sé bastante poco de servidores y no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hace tiempo me pasó algo parecido, yo tenia mi pequeña app, que usaba html, php y mysql, corriendo en un xamp en mi equipo, y pensaba que con phonegap podría copiar de mi xamp a phonegap y a funcionar.

El caso es que en phonegap no puedes hacer correr archivos php porque no tiene un compilador / procesador de php o como quieras llamarlo, así que no es tan sencillo como yo creía.

El caso, es que en la aplicación que corres en phonegap, tienes que realizar llamadas a una api que puedes crear en un servidor xamp o similar, esta api, ejecuta los archivos php, hace las consultas correspondientes a la base de datos, y te devuelve los datos en formato json.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por responder! Estoy usando socket.io (sockets) para hacer una aplicación con actualizaciones en tiempo real y no tengo ni idea como podría hacer eso que dices. He estado investigando y creo es posible crear un window view con phonegap que crea una ventana donde usas la app con el navegador, y creo que va a ser la solución más facil.

Comment: socket.io no lo he usado nunca, pero si, hacer un web view puede ser una soluciñon rápida. suerte en tu proyecto